# How could I disable my pip proxy(not in shell export)?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm using Mac, and try to install packages by pip:

```
(venv) ➜  ✗ pip install -r requirements.txt   
Collecting certifi==2019.9.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
http://127.0.0.1:6152
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x1041660d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))': /simple/certifi/
http://127.0.0.1:6152
```

I modified the code of pip so it can print which proxy I'm using.

`venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py`:`urlopen`method:

```
        elif isinstance(e, (SocketError, NewConnectionError)) and self.proxy:
            print(self.proxy) # add this line
            e = ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', e)
```

But I found nothing in my `export`:

```
(venv) ➜  ✗ export | grep proxy
(venv) ➜  ✗
```

So, how could I disable the proxy I use (http://127.0.0.1:6152)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read the code, I found in `/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py`:

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies

    def proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host):
        proxy_settings = _get_proxy_settings()
        return _proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host, proxy_settings)

    def getproxies_macosx_sysconf():
        """Return a dictionary of scheme -> proxy server URL mappings.

        This function uses the MacOSX framework SystemConfiguration
        to fetch the proxy information.
        """
        return _get_proxies()



    def proxy_bypass(host):
        """Return True, if host should be bypassed.

        Checks proxy settings gathered from the environment, if specified,
        or from the MacOSX framework SystemConfiguration.

        """
        proxies = getproxies_environment()
        if proxies:
            return proxy_bypass_environment(host, proxies)
        else:
            return proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf(host)

    def getproxies():
        return getproxies_environment() or getproxies_macosx_sysconf()
```

Please notice :

```
def getproxies():
    return getproxies_environment() or getproxies_macosx_sysconf()
```

`urllib` get proxy from two sources:

1. shell env
2. sys settings

I debugged, it got that proxy from sys. So I check my network setting:

[image: network settings]

And I found where I configured that proxy.

Comment: Nice sleuthing. This appears to be missing from [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server); maybe file a bug report?